How to transform JPEXS SWF Sprites using only the exported XML numbers
I have an XML file exported from JPEXS. Within this XML there are many, many PlaceObject2Tags and Matrices, for example:
<item type="PlaceObject2Tag" characterId="0" clipDepth="0" depth="15" ratio="0">
<matrix type="MATRIX" hasRotate="false" hasScale="true" nRotateBits="0" nScaleBits="18" nTranslateBits="13" scaleX="66428" scaleY="66427" translateX="-40" translateY="4026"/>
</item>
When I use the program JPEXS to scale the sprite up from 100% to 200% and export it again I get this result:
<matrix type="MATRIX" hasScale="true" nRotateBits="0" nScaleBits="0" nTranslateBits="0" scaleX="132856" scaleY="132854" translateX="-3020" translateY="4482"/>
I'm really hoping someone knows mathematically or programmatically how the translateX and translateY values are changed. Or if you could point me in the right direction, because every combination of equations I've tried hasn't worked at all to go from -40 to -3020, and from 4026 to 4482. Thanks!
I believe it's something to do with the scale being calculated by 66428 - 65535 = 893 and then using that number somehow, but I don't know.
I've also used the hex tags because maybe the nTranslateBits=13 has something to do with it.
